# How to pass javascript function into another function without predefining?

Tags: javascript, function

I have something like this in `angularJS`:

```
var onErr = function() {};
var sent = httpService.handleRequest(onErr);
```

I want to pass the function without defining in another line. Because there are many functions that return nothing.

What I exactly mean, is something like this:

```
// no definition
var sent = httpService.handleRequest(new function1, new function2);
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to pass anything? Could you not just pass null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the function inline:

```
var sent = httpService.handleRequest(function () {}, function () {});
```

Though I'm not clear on why the return value of the function you pass in has anything to do with why you want to declare them inline instead of beforehand?

Comment: oh, yes, I thing I have had something wrong, because of that I was getting error. I want them inline, because I didn't want to have 5 or 6 lines for only defining empty function. Any way , thank you.

Comment: If you have empty functions pass around a lot, just create 1 `nop` function and pass it around. `var nop = function () {};` So you aren't creating a new empty function every time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the original concept with a no operation function, as you have.

```
var nop = function() {};
var sent = httpService.handleRequest(nop, nop);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anonymous function.

```
var sent = httpService.handleRequest(function() {}, function() {});
```

An anonymous function is a function without a name and can be used as a parameter of another function.